# how to convert huggingface datasets to json and vice versa?

Tags: json, huggingface-datasets

based on some examples , I can load a huggingfac dataset and convert it to a json file with to_json method. how can i convert a json file to hugging face dataset?

```
ds = load_dataset(./file_path, split="train")        
ds.to_json("dataset.json")
```